# How to fix com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException

Tags: java, json

I am trying to read a file from an external URL. The file contains data in JSON format. I am using the following code to read data from the file:

```
URL url = new URL(url);
URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
request.connect();JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(rootobj.toString());
```

But I am getting the following exception while trying to run the code:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 2 column 2
```

How can I fix this error? I have been spending some time now online to find s solution, but nothing helped me.

I am adding the sample data below:

```
{"address":"P.O. Box 939","city":"Indian River","country":"US","dateAdded":"2018-02-08T04:35:45Z","dateUpdated":"2018-02-08T04:35:45Z","descriptions":[{"dateSeen":["2018-02-01T21:34:00.000Z"],"sourceURLs":["https://www.weddingwire.com/biz/rental-express-indian-river/2274f039e0c45443.html"],"value":"Contact Rental Express in Indian River on WeddingWire. Browse Event Rentals prices, photos and 1 reviews, with a rating of 5.0 out of 5"}],"features":[{"key":"Average Rating","value":["5.0"]},{"key":"Event Items","value":["Chairs","Dance Floor","Lights","Photobooth","Tables","Tent Accessories","Tents"]},{"key":"Food/Beverage Items","value":["China","Flatware","Glassware","Linens"]}],"keys":["us/mi/indianriver/p.o.box939/-1646083636"],"latitude":"45.4125117","longitude":"-84.6125364","name":"Rental Express","phones":["2312389696"],"postalCode":"49749","province":"MI","sourceURLs":["https://www.weddingwire.com/biz/rental-express-indian-river/2274f039e0c45443.html"],"id":"AWFztIreIxWefVJwy6hK"}
{"address":"PO Box 6479","city":"Silver Spring","country":"US","dateAdded":"2018-02-08T04:35:35Z","dateUpdated":"2018-02-08T04:35:35Z","descriptions":[{"dateSeen":["2018-02-01T06:27:00.000Z"],"sourceURLs":["https://www.weddingwire.com/biz/indian-spring-country-club-silver-spring/9c020a063ea0fc84.html"],"value":"Contact Indian Spring Country Club in Silver Spring on WeddingWire. Browse Venue prices, photos and 3 reviews, with a rating of 4.3 out of 5"}],"features":[{"key":"Average Rating","value":["4.3"]}],"keys":["us/md/silverspring/pobox6479/1573156840"],"name":"Indian Spring Country Club","phones":["3018716000"],"postalCode":"20916","province":"MD","sourceURLs":["https://www.weddingwire.com/biz/indian-spring-country-club-silver-spring/9c020a063ea0fc84.html"],"id":"AWFztWW0IxWefVJwy7PH"}
```

Comment: Is the JSON actually valid? Check it: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @ Øyvind Hauge, I am getting the data from an external URL which is supposed to provide me a valid JSON data. The data is very large.

Comment: Try using a minimal JSON example with your implementation: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1

Does it work? If it does, then the original JSON response is probably invalid (according to the RFC 4627).

Comment: The JSON objects should be wrapped in an array (hence the "INVALID JSON (RFC 4627) Multiple JSON root elements" error). On the server side, wrap all elements in a JSON array: [ {object}, {object}, {object}, ... ] and it should be valid.

Comment: @ Øyvind Hauge, how can I do this to a data that I get from a remote file in which I have no access. http://d1kv7s9g8y3npv.cloudfront.net/testsite/files/doc-lib/2018/05/15/04/01/09/142/head/test.txt.txt would be a file with similar data

Comment: I'd suggest to contact the people with access and have them fix the JSON structure. If this is not an option, then you need to use setLenient(true) and handle the invalid JSON in the client yourself.

Comment: @Øyvind Hauge, I am ok with using the setLenient(true). But I want to get all the data into a JSON array so that I can loop over each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help...

```
JsonReader jr = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
jr.setLenient(true); //like the expetion says to accept the malformed json
JsonElement root = jp.parse(jr);
```

https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html#setLenient-boolean-

https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html

Comment: thanks, that worked. Is there any way I can parse data using multiple URLs in a loop and add everything into a single JSON array.

Comment: This works, but might cause problems further down the line when you actually try to use the JSON, since it might not be in the format you expect.

Comment: @Øyvind Hauge, this worked, but it gives me a single JSON object. The data consist of multiple JSON objects. I am unable to get the entire data this way

Comment: Is the web resource for the JOSN publicly available? If so, you could post the link and I'll take a look. @GeoThomas

Comment: @Øyvind Hauge , I might not be able to provide you the URL, but I have added sample data to my question. Also when I tried that data in a  JSON formatter, it was giving an error: INVALID JSON (RFC 4627) Multiple JSON root elements

Comment: @Wufo, I am accepting this as the answer since it solved the exception and that was the question.

Answer (score 2):

To your first question, **MalformedJsonException** indicates that your input might not be a valid json; I would check that with an online json formatter/validator, such as [this](https://jsonlint.com/) one before ignoring with **setLenient(true)**.

To your second question: how o construct a Json array with multiple URLs, this is one way to do it:

```
    try {
        // Here I use github api as a sample service:
        URL url1 = new URL("https://api.github.com/users/n1");
        URL url2 = new URL("https://api.github.com/users/n2");

        List<URL> urlsList = new ArrayList<URL>();
        urlsList.add(url1);
        urlsList.add(url2);

        JsonArray jsonArr = new JsonArray();
        for (URL url : urlsList) {
            URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
            request.connect();
            JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonParser().parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())).getAsJsonObject();
            jsonArr.add(jsonObj);   
        }
        System.out.println(jsonArr.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do something here...
    }
```

**An update:**

I checked your URL, and as I stated before it's an invalid json.
In this case, you'll have get the request content as a string and convert it to a valid json manually (add brackets). Then the parsing will work.

This code will do it:

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://d1kv7s9g8y3npv.cloudfront.net/testsite/files/doc-lib/2018/05/15/04/01/09/142/head/test.txt.txt");
        URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
        request.connect();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String content = rd.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
        JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse("["  + content + "]");
        System.out.println(jsonElement.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do something here...
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: there is a small issue with the data I get from the URLs. I have posted the sample in my question. Also I will have to use setLenient(true), since I do not have control over the data.